# Bundle React and Springboot Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-security

I'm trying to bundle my React and Springboot Project to run on the same port. Whenever I run them separately, it works fine. React running on 3000 and springboot server running on 8080. However, whenever I try to run the JAR file I get a 401 error. I have the maven resources plugin copying the frontend files to the static folder. How can I solve this error? All my security files down below...

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebMvc
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static final String[] PUBLIC_URL={
            "/index.html", "/", "/home","/login",
            "/api/v1/auth/register",
            "/api/v1/auth/authenticate",
            "/api/v1/articles/**",
            "/api/v1/comments/get/**",
            "/api/v1/contact/**",
            "/api/v1/admin/login",
            "/api/v1/file/**",
            "/api/v1/seller/login**"
    };
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .antMatchers(PUBLIC_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

    }



    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

**JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint.java**

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,"Access Denined !");

    }
}
```

**JWTAuthenticationfilter.java**

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenHelper jwtTokenHelper;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) {

        String requestToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        System.out.println(requestToken);

        String username = null;
        String token = null;

        if (requestToken != null && requestToken.startsWith("Bearer")) {

            token = requestToken.substring(7);

            try {
                username = jwtTokenHelper.extractUsername(token);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException r) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get Jwt token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("Token has expired");
            } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("invalid jwt");

            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Jwt token does not start with Bearer");
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtTokenHelper.validateToken(token, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken=new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,null,userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            } else {
                System.out.println("invalid jwt");

            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("invalid jwt");

        }

        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>GameReviewz</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GameReviewz</name>
    <description>SpringBoot Application for GameReviewz</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <from>
                        <image>openjdk:17</image>
                    </from>
                    <container>
                        <ports>
                            <port>8080</port>
                        </ports>
                        <format>OCI</format>
                    </container>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>build-frontend</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <!-- Use the latest released version:
                                  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/ -->
                        <version>1.12.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v4.6.0</nodeVersion>
                            <workingDirectory>src/frontend</workingDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install node and npm</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <nodeVersion>v16.16.0</nodeVersion>
                                    <npmVersion>8.11.0</npmVersion>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>npm install</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>npm run build</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>run build</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-build-folder</id>
                                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>src/frontend/build</directory>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: you can enable spring DEBUG level logs and post them in full here so we can see the reason for the 401. Also, `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated, and you should upgrade to spring boot 3 and Spring Security 6. Also is there any reason to why you are not using the built in handling of JWTs that already comes with spring security? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html and here is an example https://github.com/Tandolf/spring-security-jwt-demo